# How can I compare a start date and end date using the jQuery Datepicker?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-datepicker

I use the jQuery `Datepicker` for two different text fields. One field for start date and another for end field. I disable date before current date using `minDate`. My code is like this:

```
$( "#start" ).datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    showOnFocus: true,
    showTrigger: '<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/calender.png" />'
});    

$( "#end" ).datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    showOnFocus: true,
    showTrigger: '<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/calender.png" />'
});
```

Now I need to check that end date must be equal to or greater than start date. And in the end date field, all dates before the start date selected must be disabled. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly thanks to all who help me to find the answer.

Solution for my question is by using following codes:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#depart ,#return_date").datepick({
    minDate:0,
    dateFormat:'yyyy-mm-dd',
    showOnFocus: true,
    showTrigger: '<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/calender.png" />',
    onSelect: customRange
  });

  function customRange(dates) {
    if (this.id == 'depart')
    {
      $('#return_date').datepick('option', 'minDate', dates[0] || null);
    }
    else
    {
      $('#depart').datepick('option', 'maxDate', dates[0] || null);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example of the code that is required.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                    instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                    date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                        instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                        $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                        selectedDate, instance.settings );
                dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

You can view the demo at: [Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range)

Referred from the Jquery UI website.

Comment: i must challenge you that my answer is more readable. what do you say? :)

Answer (score 0):

Use datejs library for complex date related manipulations --> datejs.com

Answer (score 0):

you need to reset end date when start date changes.
this should do it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#start').datepicker({
            minDate: '-1d',
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            showTrigger: '<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/calender.png" />'
        });

        $('#end').datepicker({
            minDate: '-1d',
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            showTrigger: '<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/calender.png" />'
        });

        $('#start').change(function () {
            var sDate = $('#start').val().split("-");
            var endMinDate = new Date(sDate[0], sDate[1] - 1, sDate[2]);
            $('#end').datepicker('option', 'minDate', endMinDate);
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: This code not working....I just want all days before current days disable for start text field and in the case of end text field i want all days before date inserted in start text field is disable.How to be done in above code.......